# stripes while calculating image gradient with CUDA

Tags: image-processing, cuda, artifacts

I'm writing a code for the image denoising and came across a strange problem with stripes in the processed images. Basically when I'm calculating X-gradient of image the horizontal stripes appear (or vertical for Y direction) [Lena X gradient](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8910265/Lena_Grad.png).
The whole algorithm works OK and it looks like I'm getting the correct answer (I'm comparing with program in C) except those annoying stripes [Lena result](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8910265/Lena_Stripes.png).

The distance between stripes is changing with different block sizes. I'm also having different stripes positions each time I run the program! Here is the part of the program related to the gradient calculation. I have a feeling that I'm doing something very stupid :) Thank you!

```
 #define BLKXSIZE 16
 #define BLKYSIZE 16
 #define idivup(a, b) ( ((a)%(b) != 0) ? (a)/(b)+1 : (a)/(b) )
 void Diff4th_GPU(float* A, float* B, int N, int M, int Z, float sigma, int iter, float tau, int                           type)
 {
    float *Ad; 

dim3 dimBlock(BLKXSIZE,BLKYSIZE);
dim3 dimGrid(idivup(N,BLKXSIZE), idivup(M,BLKYSIZE));

cudaMalloc((void**)&Ad,N*M*sizeof(float));        


cudaMemcpy(Ad,A,N*M*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

cudaCheckErrors("cc1");
int n = 1;
while (n <= iter) {
    Diff4th2D<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Ad, N, M, sigma, iter, tau, type);
    n++;
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("kernel");}

cudaMemcpy(B,Ad,N*M*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaCheckErrors("cc2");
cudaFree(Ad);
 } 

  __global__ void Diff4th2D(float* A, int N, int M, float sigma, int iter, float tau, int type)
 {

float gradX, gradX_sq, gradY, gradY_sq, gradXX, gradYY, gradXY, sq_sum, xy_2, Lam,    V_norm, V_orth, c, c_sq, lam_t;


int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

 int index = j + i*N;

if ((i < N) && (j < M))
  {
    float gradX = 0, gradY = 0, gradXX = 0, gradYY = 0,  gradXY = 0;

    if ((i>1) && (i<N)) {
        if ((j>1) && (j<M)){
    int indexN = (j)+(i-1)*(N);
    if (indexN > ((N*M)-1)) indexN = (N*M)-1;
    if (indexN < 0) indexN = 0;
    int indexS = (j)+(i+1)*(N);
    if (indexS > ((N*M)-1)) indexS = (N*M)-1;
    if (indexS < 0) indexS = 0;
    int indexW = (j-1)+(i)*(N);
    if (indexW > ((N*M)-1)) indexW = (N*M)-1;
    if (indexW < 0) indexW = 0;
    int indexE = (j+1)+(i)*(N);        
    if (indexE > ((N*M)-1)) indexE = (N*M)-1;
    if (indexE < 0) indexE = 0;

   gradX = 0.5*(A[indexN]-A[indexS]);
   A[index] = gradX;
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition inside your kernel, as elements of A may or may not be overwritten before they are used.

Use different arrays for input and output.

Comment: thanks a lot, it did the trick! Looks like the CPU programming habits should be reconsidered significantly :)